# Understanding CSS line wrapping with different font-sizes

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-size

Consider this example:

```css
div.big {
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: bold;
}

div.big .small {
  font-size: 40%;
}

div.small {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  font-weight: bold;
}

div.small .big {
  font-size: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="big">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <span class="small">consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</span></div>
<p>Something else</p>

<div class="small"><span class="big">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, </span>consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</div>
<p>Something else</p>
```

In the first case (small font-size inline element inside a bigger font-size block element), the spacing around the wrapped text isn't the same as in the second case (big font-size inline element inside a smaller font-size block element).

[image: Preview 1]

It gets even more obvious when wrapping on multiple lines:

[image: Preview 2]

What is the property/behavior that causes this difference, and is there a way to make the first example look like the second one without changing the markup?

Comment: @johannes adding the line-height tag means that the OP is aware about line-height which is not the case so the tag will create confusion

Comment: @TemaniAfif But the OP asked "What is the property/behavior that causes this difference", and that's line-height, in this case the default line-height of the browser. I also wrote in my answer that it's not a good idea to do what I demonstrated...

Comment: @Johannes yes and line-height should be in the answers, not the question. It doesn't make sense to ask about an unknown property that is present in the question.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Ah - you mean the tagging I added - sorry, I missed that. Yes, you are right.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Welcome to SO.

Just add `display: contents;` to

```
div.big {
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: contents;
}
```

DEMO:

```css
div.big {
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: contents;
}

div.big .small {
  font-size: 40%;
}

div.small {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  font-weight: bold;
}

div.small .big {
  font-size: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="big">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <span class="small">consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</span></div>
<p>Something else</p>

<div class="small"><span class="big">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, </span>consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</div>
<p>Something else</p>
```

Comment: note that this property definitely still lacks browser support: https://caniuse.com/?search=display%3A%20contents%3B

Comment: It is still covering Global 90.78% and mostly this days only ie not accepting it.

Comment: That's a great trick. Would there be a way of adding margin around the container without modifying the markup?

Comment: Margin top and bottom are possible by using: property `:before` and `:after`. such as: `div.big:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    margin: 10px;`

Answer (score 1):

The reason for what you see is the `line-height`, which by default is relative to the `font-size`, i.e. to the `font-size` of the parent/block element. It usually is defined in percent or as a multiplication factor like `1.6` - if you don't see any such parameter in the stylesheet, there's still an according browser default setting, usually between 1.4 and 1.6.

If you set the line-height to a fixed pixel value (which in real life you should almost never do), both examples look the same, as in the following variation of your code:

```css
div.big {
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 16px;
}

div.big .small {
  font-size: 40%;
}

div.small {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 16px;

}

div.small .big {
  font-size: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="big">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <span class="small">consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</span></div>
<p>Something else</p>

<div class="small"><span class="big">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, </span>consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</div>
<p>Something else</p>
```

Comment: When you reduce browser width, your solution do not work... Big characters are going over each other.

Comment: @MaxiGui Yes f course, because, the line-height is a fixed pixel value. The example (also) shows that (as I wrote in my answer) you *should not* use this, unless you are very aware of what you are doing and of possible consequences.